# Splittinf field of a product of irreducible polynomials over Finite Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

I was wondering if someone knew a reference, that I could look up, of what I think is a fact that:

If $f(x), g(x)$ are two irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, for $p$ a prime, of respective degrees $n,m$. Then the splitting field of $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is simply $F_{p^d}$, where $d=lcm(m,n).$

I recall reading about this at some point, but I cannot seem to find a reference.

Thanks!

Comment: A splitting field of $h$ has to be a splitting field for both $f$ and $g$. What are the respective splitting fields of $f$ and $g$? What is the smallest field that contains both of those?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Got it! Great!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Good. May be you flesh out the argument to an answer?